# Scroll issue in responsive website

Tags: html, css

I've fixed header and footer. Only the body needs to be scrolled. So I used a code like this:

```
.body{
height: 100%;
margin: 0%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

But it didn't work. How can I make only body scrollable?

Comment: If you have the header and footer `position: fixed` then you don't need to set these attributes to the body.

Comment: Please provide full code that will demonstrate the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

try to add to your style:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Comment: can you create a simple plunkr it will be easier to find solution.